# (Unity Error)The option 'android.enableR8' is deprecated and should not be used anymore. It will be removed in a future version of the Android Gradle

Tags: unity-game-engine, appodeal

I can drop everything you need to help me

> Configure project :launcher
> WARNING: The option 'android.enableR8' is deprecated and should not be used anymore.
> It will be removed in a future version of the Android Gradle plugin, and will no longer allow you to disable R8.

> Task :launcher:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:GooglePlayGamesManifest.plugin:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:GooglePlayGamesManifest.plugin:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:packageReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:GooglePlayGamesManifest.plugin:compileReleaseAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :launcher:compileReleaseAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :launcher:compileReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:GooglePlayGamesManifest.plugin:packageReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:GooglePlayGamesManifest.plugin:compileReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:GooglePlayGamesManifest.plugin:generateReleaseResValues
> Task :unityLibrary:GooglePlayGamesManifest.plugin:generateReleaseResources
> Task :unityLibrary:packageReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:GooglePlayGamesManifest.plugin:packageReleaseResources
> Task :unityLibrary:parseReleaseLocalResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:GooglePlayGamesManifest.plugin:parseReleaseLocalResources
> Task :unityLibrary:GooglePlayGamesManifest.plugin:generateReleaseBuildConfig
> Task :unityLibrary:GooglePlayGamesManifest.plugin:javaPreCompileRelease
> Task :unityLibrary:GooglePlayGamesManifest.plugin:processReleaseManifest
> Task :unityLibrary:processReleaseManifest
> Task :unityLibrary:GooglePlayGamesManifest.plugin:generateReleaseRFile
> Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseRFile UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:mainApkListPersistenceRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:GooglePlayGamesManifest.plugin:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac
> Task :unityLibrary:GooglePlayGamesManifest.plugin:bundleLibCompileRelease
> Task :unityLibrary:javaPreCompileRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:extractDeepLinksRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:GooglePlayGamesManifest.plugin:extractDeepLinksRelease
> Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseLibraryResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:GooglePlayGamesManifest.plugin:compileReleaseLibraryResources
> Task :unityLibrary:bundleLibCompileRelease
> Task :launcher:mergeReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:createReleaseCompatibleScreenManifests UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:extractDeepLinksRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:prepareLintJarForPublish UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:GooglePlayGamesManifest.plugin:prepareLintJarForPublish UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:GooglePlayGamesManifest.plugin:bundleLibRuntimeRelease
> Task :unityLibrary:bundleLibRuntimeRelease

> Task :launcher:processReleaseManifest
> C:\Unity and other\Project\HelixJumpFirstPerson\Temp\gradleOut\launcher\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml:23:5-81 Warning:
> uses-permission#android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE was tagged at AndroidManifest.xml:23 to replace another declaration but no other declaration present

> Task :unityLibrary:GooglePlayGamesManifest.plugin:mergeReleaseShaders
> Task :unityLibrary:mergeReleaseShaders
> Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseShaders
> Task :unityLibrary:GooglePlayGamesManifest.plugin:compileReleaseShaders
> Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseAssets
> Task :unityLibrary:GooglePlayGamesManifest.plugin:generateReleaseAssets
> Task :unityLibrary:GooglePlayGamesManifest.plugin:packageReleaseAssets
> Task :unityLibrary:packageReleaseAssets
> Task :unityLibrary:processReleaseJavaRes NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:GooglePlayGamesManifest.plugin:processReleaseJavaRes NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:GooglePlayGamesManifest.plugin:bundleLibResRelease
> Task :unityLibrary:bundleLibResRelease
> Task :unityLibrary:GooglePlayGamesManifest.plugin:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders
> Task :unityLibrary:GooglePlayGamesManifest.plugin:mergeReleaseNativeLibs
> Task :unityLibrary:GooglePlayGamesManifest.plugin:stripReleaseDebugSymbols
> Task :unityLibrary:GooglePlayGamesManifest.plugin:copyReleaseJniLibsProjectOnly
> Task :unityLibrary:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders
> Task :unityLibrary:mergeReleaseNativeLibs
> Task :unityLibrary:stripReleaseDebugSymbols
> Task :unityLibrary:copyReleaseJniLibsProjectOnly
> Task :launcher:processReleaseResources
> Task :launcher:prepareLintJar UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:javaPreCompileRelease
> Task :launcher:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac
> Task :launcher:compileReleaseSources
> Task :launcher:lintVitalRelease
> Task :launcher:checkReleaseDuplicateClasses FAILED
> 55 actionable tasks: 37 executed, 18 up-to-date

UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)

Comment: Same problem here. you are using Firebase SDK right?

Comment: That's not an *error*. It's a **warning** that's telling you that you need to change your code, because there are changes coming in the future. It tells you what that change will be. Did you bother to read the words in the warning message?

Answer (score -1):

Are you using a package you imported? I had incorrectly imported the ARCore Extensions package by placing it in the Packages folder of my project and got this error (or one similar). If you imported a package the same way, this is likely the problem. (The correct way is `Window>Package Manager>+ (dropdown)>Add package from disk>package.json`.)

Answer (score -1):

On Unity v.2021.1.16f1 and Firebase 8.8.0 have same problem.

My solution: **Minimum API Level = API 21**

Answer (score -2):

You Should Try This Check the Checkbox `Ignore Gradle Version` under project settings>Xr-pluginManagement>ARCore.

See The Screen Shot Below.

[ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DJS3o.png)

Comment: you **must** delete "Temp" folder before re-build

Answer (score -2):

Try checking **Use R8** in `Project Settings/Player/Publishing Settings/Minify`